# Playing multiple files in MediaPlayer one after other In android

Tags: android

I am having Problem in playing multiple mp3 files in MediaPlayer for android ...It plays all files together and creates mess.I want the solution that it just play each file at a time and then after it other file get played.

Comment: use exoPlayer.
this library help you to concatenate multi video together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is various MediaPlayer callback use them like  :

http://www.androidadb.com/class/on/OnCompletionListener.html

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer theMediaPlayer) {
        mParent.playNextAudio();
        mParent = null;
    }
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29)

Comment: String PATH_TO_FILE = "/sdcard/my_downloads/ "+ filenum + ".mp3";
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
mediaPlayer.prepare();


mediaPlayer.start();




mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // TODO





String path = "/sdcard/my_downloads/ "+ filenum + ".mp3";
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mediaPlayer.prepare();


mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception

}
filenum++;

}
});

Comment: I implemented this but...it's not working properly...it only plays first 2 files

Comment: I have the same, it only plays the first two files. You seem to have to add an oncompletionlistener to theMediaPlayer. No idea how though...

Comment: but beware you may hear mp3s twice :/

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
{
    int[] tracks = new int[3];
    int currentTrack = 0;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      tracks[0] = R.raw.say1;
      tracks[1] = R.raw.say2;
      tracks[2] = R.raw.say3;
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
      arg0.release();
      if (currentTrack < tracks.length) {
        currentTrack++;
        arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        arg0.start();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only executes first two audio files ,the third one does not play. Why is this happening ,do you have any fix for it?

Answer (score 5):

I did this by following code:

```
private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> mPlayerList = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
public void playSound4FileList(ArrayList<String> fileList) 
{
    mPlayerList.clear();
    for (String fileName : fileList)
    {
        try {
            MediaPlayer mPlayerT = new MediaPlayer();

            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
            mPlayerT.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();

            mPlayerT.prepare();
            mPlayerT.setVolume(1f, 1f);
            mPlayerT.setLooping(false);

            mPlayerList.add(mPlayerT);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    for (int i=0; i<mPlayerList.size()-1; i++) //Do not include last element
    {
        mPlayerList.get(i).setNextMediaPlayer(mPlayerList.get(i+1));

    }

    mPlayerList.get(0).start();
}
```

Comment: Call requires API level 16 : android.media.MediaPlayer#setNextMediaPlayer !

Comment: This works but consumes SO MUCH memory!! Be careful...