# App Crashing when playing sounds in succession in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I found the following code as an answer to a question here [Playing multiple files in MediaPlayer one after other In android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916129/playing-multiple-files-in-mediaplayer-one-after-other-in-android)

When I run it, the 3 sounds are played but then the app closes with the message

> unfortunately the application has stopped.

Is there something missing inside the `onCompletion` method?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    int[] tracks = new int[3];
    int currentTrack = 0;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tracks[0] = R.raw.p46;
        tracks[1] = R.raw.p52;
        tracks[2] = R.raw.p55;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        arg0.release();
        if (currentTrack < tracks.length) {
            currentTrack++;
            arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
            arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            arg0.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this just an error with your if statement. You're incrementing `currentTrack` after range checking, resulting in an out of bounds exception.

Comment: I think the error mught be coming from `            arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);` in your onCompletion method try removing it and see if it doesnt throw an error after the first song

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        arg0.release();
        if (currentTrack < tracks.length) {
            currentTrack++;
            arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
            arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            arg0.start();
        }
    }
```

to :

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        arg0.release();
        currentTrack++;
        if (currentTrack < tracks.length) {

            arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
            arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            arg0.start();
        }
    }
```

basically you are getting a `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException` becoz at last currentTrack is 3 and and there is no item at index 3 i.e 4th item

Comment: This fixed the problem, but now if I move the sound playing code from onCreate to buttonTapped, the app crashs again. '    public void buttonTapped(View view){
        tracks[0] = R.raw.pianoff46;
        tracks[1] = R.raw.pianoff52;
        tracks[2] = R.raw.pianoff55;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

Comment: that is a different issue pls open another question for that and also pls post stacktrace this time

Comment: there is a check button left to each answer click that