# MediaPlayer Crashing my App (edit: it was caused by an out of bound array)

Tags: java, android

As a follow up to this question [App Crashing when playing sounds in succession in MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025197/app-crashing-when-playing-sounds-in-succession-in-mediaplayer)

I copied the code from `onCreate` into another method (named `buttonTapped`). The app plays the sound correctly during `onCreate`, but crashes without playing any sounds when the `buttonTapped` method is called (by tapping a button). The error message is:

> unfortunately the application has stopped.

Here is the code, followed by the stack trace

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    int[] tracks = new int[3];
    int currentTrack = 0;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;    

    public void buttonTapped(View view){
        tracks[0] = R.raw.p46;
        tracks[1] = R.raw.p52;
        tracks[2] = R.raw.p55;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tracks[0] = R.raw.p46;
        tracks[1] = R.raw.p52;
        tracks[2] = R.raw.p55;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();    
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        arg0.release();
        currentTrack++;

        if (currentTrack < tracks.length) {
            arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
            arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            arg0.start();
        }
    }

  530-530/com.maxd.soundtesting E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.maxd.soundtesting, PID: 530
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
            at com.maxd.soundtesting.MainActivity.buttonTapped(MainActivity.java:22)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3 at com.maxd.soundtesting.MainActivity.buttonTapped(MainActivity.java:22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In button tapped, you aren't resetting the currentTrack to 0. So after onCreate has played the 3 sounds, currentTrack = 3, and that is an invalid index as current track can only equal 0, 1, or 2.