# Mediaplayer is playing random songs

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Im using the following code to play music.

```
if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } else {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
```

**Explanation:**

- when the user clicks a song for the first time, else loop will be
  executed.
- If the user clicks a song when the mediaplayer is playing a song already, if loop will
  be executed
- In my if loop, Im resetting the mediaplayer before setting the data source so it calls the onCompletion listener.

Follwing is my onCompletionListener.

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
                    MainActivity.nextTrackController.performClick();
        });
```

Following is my nextTrackController onClickListener.

```
 MainActivity.nextTrackController.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            try {
                if (MainActivity.currentOffset < (MainActivity.localTrackList.size() - 1)) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    } else {
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    }

                    MainActivity.currentOffset = MainActivity.currentOffset + 1;
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } else {

                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                    MainActivity.currentOffset = 0;
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        });
```

the problem is that,

1. If the media player is playing and if the user is clicking a song, it is not playing the specific song that had been clicked but it plays some random song.
2. If the song finished playing, it plays a random song instead of the next song. How can i be able to sort this out?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916129/playing-multiple-files-in-mediaplayer-one-after-other-in-android

Comment: does mediaplyer.reset calls onCompletionListener?